# Passing return values from php api array to another page

Tags: php, arrays, api, ionic-framework, ionic2

In my ionic app I tried passing array returned from a php api to another page but it was not passing any values

In user.html page I have the button that when click pass the value to the next page

```
<button ion-button icon-only (click)="goToResult()">
    <ion-icon ios="ios-log-out" md="md-log-out" class="user"></ion-icon> Next
</button>
```

**userHome.ts**

```
ngOnInit(){

this.phone = this.navParams.get('phone');


var headers = new Headers();

headers.append("Accept", 'application/json');

headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json' );

let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers });

let data = {

    phone: this.phone

     };

let loader = this.loading.create({

content: 'Loading Page Contents',

});

loader.present().then(() => {

this.http.post('http://mypro.com/eApi/retrieve.php',data, options)

.map(res => res.json())

    .subscribe(res => {

     loader.dismiss()

    this.items=res.server_response;

    console.log(this.items);

    });

    });
    //this.navCtrl.push(PostPage, data); 
  }
```

On the same page, this is the push nav I tried passing the values through

```
goToResult(){
    console.log(this.items);
      this.navCtrl.push(PostPage,
        this.postList = this.items
      )

  }
```

In post.ts, I added this to the contructor

```
this.navParams.get(this.postList);
```

then in my **post.html**

```
<ion-title *ngFor="let post of postList">{{post.Name}}
        </ion-title>
```

Please, how can I pass the return values from the api to another page?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So if you check ionic doc example you will see that you need to pass data using json object and use its key to retrieve data, try this approach:

In your first component:

```
   this.navCtrl.push(PostPage,
        { postList: this.items } 
   )
```

In receiving component constructor;

```
this.postList = this.navParams.get(“postList”);
```

If still struggle please share full code, but this should be easy fix;)

Answer (score 0):

you can do like this

```
goToResult(){
    console.log(this.items);
      this.navCtrl.push(PostPage, {postList = this.items})
}
```

In post.ts, you can get value by

```
this.navParams.get('postList');
```